# Extract assembly from a particular namespace with Reflection

Tags: roslyn, system.reflection, reflection.emit

I need to extract separate assembly from a particular namespace in an assembly.
I can see separate name spaces when open the assembly with ILSpy, so I assume this can be done using  System.Reflection library.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this? Or any alternative approach for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically or just one time to get the paticular namespace as seperate assembly?

Comment: @thehennyy I need to do this programmatically.

Comment: Since a namespace is nothing more than a naming convention i would probably go with `mono.cecil` or `dnlib` to remove all types that are not needed and see from there what else have to be removed (resources, ...). `ildasm` - `ilasm` roundtripping and string manipulation should work too. `Reflection.Emit` can work in theory but you would have to recreate the whole assembly and code structure and roslyn only works on source code afaik.